# java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero when compress image from pick gallery

Tags: java, android

I'm getting error `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` when compress image from pick gallery. this Is my code:

```
 public String compressImage(String filePath, String outputFilename) {

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
        Log.i("INFO", "ActualHeight Input: " + actualHeight);
        Log.i("INFO", "ActualWidth Input: " + actualWidth);

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;


       ............

        return outputFilename;
    }
```

the error get in lin : `float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;` so how to fix it?

Comment: i just copy from people code, and i don't know how to fix it

Comment: What part of this don't you understand? The error is "divide by zero". You're dividing by `actualHeight`. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is there an actual file at `filePath`?

Comment: i copy from there sir > http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Comment: My browser won't load it.

Comment: But here's the issue I'm trying to address... In the first line of the code you posted, it says `public String compressImage(String filePath, ...`. You have to be invoking this method somewhere, and when you do, are you using a path to a real file somewhere? I think you're not, i.e. that `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` can't find an actual file where you've told it to look, and so nothing is coming back right.

Comment: i get error if. picture is small size, like thumbnail, but big size ist not error size

Comment: @AmayDiam do you fix this error? I obtain the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are getting the exception says that division by zero is occurring, and that `options.outHeight` is returning zero. You need to find out why that is happening. 
If `Log.i("INFO", "ActualHeight Input: " + actualHeight);` returns you something other than `null`, provide us more details.

Comment: i get error if. picture is small size, like thumbnail, but big size ist not error size

Comment: and when you're checking value of `options.outHeight`, it shows what?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line on your manifest (inside the Application block).

> Android: requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"

Hope, this will be helpful on this issue.